# Continuation token - CreateDocumentQuery ExecuteNextAsync function not exist

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I develop in c# in azure documentDB platform .
I try to implement paging architecture in my application .
My code :

```
var userQuery = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<User>(
                _uriUsersCollection, queryStr, options).AsDocumentQuery();
```

my code show error on the  AsDocumentQuery() function (it's not recognize as part of the IQueryable methods (I see several example in the internet that the function is recognize ).So when I try to activate the query.ExecuteNextAsync it is not exist.
I work with Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client dll version 1.11.0.0.
Thanks for your help
MAK

Answer (score 6):

For scenarios with Continuation Token I often use this helper class:

```
public class PagedResults<T>
{
    public PagedResults()
    {
        Results = new List<T>();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Continuation Token for DocumentDB
    /// </summary>
    public string ContinuationToken { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Results
    /// </summary>
    public List<T> Results { get; set; }
}
```

With [this extension](https://github.com/ealsur/auth0documentdb/blob/master/Extensions/DocumentDbLinqExtensions.cs#L36):

```
public static async Task<PagedResults<T>> ToPagedResults<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
{
    var documentQuery = source.AsDocumentQuery();
    var results = new PagedResults<T>();

    try
    {
        var queryResult = await documentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
        if (!queryResult.Any())
        {
            return results;
        }
        results.ContinuationToken = queryResult.ResponseContinuation;
        results.Results.AddRange(queryResult);
    }
    catch
    {
        //documentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync throws an Exception if there are no results
        return results;
    }

    return results;
}
```

Now, you can use it in your code more or less like this:

```
var options = new FeedOptions() { MaxItemCount = 20 };//If 20 is your page size
var continuationToken = string.Empty;
var allResults = new List<User>();
do{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuationToken))
    {
            options.RequestContinuation = continuationToken;
    }
    var userQuery = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<User>(_uriUsersCollection, queryStr, options).ToPagedResults();
    continuationToken = userQuery.ContinuationToken;
    allResults.AddRange(userQuery.Results);     
}while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuationToken));
```

Answer (score 3):

Please include `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq` namespace in your code as `AsDocumentQuery` is an extension method defined there.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq;//Add this line
```

[image]